# EntityExistsException when creating new element

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is my bean :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "cl_id")
private Long clId;

@JoinColumn(name = "zip_id", referencedColumnName = "zip_id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Zip zipId;
@JoinColumn(name = "city_id", referencedColumnName = "city_id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private City cityId;
@JoinColumn(name = "street_id", referencedColumnName = "street_id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Street streetId;
```

My problem is, whenever I try to insert a new client that uses 
an already existant zip, city or street I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: 
Exception Description: Cannot persist detached object [bean.Zip[zipId=17]]. 
Class> com.jresto.common.bean.Zip Primary Key> [17]
at  oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:208)
```

It doesn't consider the **CascadeType.MERGE** part.

Comment: I stand corrected, try this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/

Answer (score 0):

You're persisting a new Bean (assuming that's the name of your entity). And you told Hibernate that whenever you persist a Bean, persist() must also be called on the zip of the Bean. And the bean contains a zip which has an ID of a zip which already exists in the database. So obviously, you get this exception.

Either use merge() instead of persist, or look up the zip from the session, attach the retrieved persistent zip to the bean, and persist the bean.

Cascading a ManyToOne association is a bit strange. You have several bean instances sharing a single zip, and whenever you modify one of the beans, the zip is modified for all the other beans.